# Different words for "hole"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

Spanish has several words that could be translated "hole" in English:

- hoyo
- agujero
- hueco
- bache
- boquete
- brecha
- madriguera

What are the differences between these words? In what situations can each be used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- **Hoyo**: Apertura en el suelo.

  > *El golf consiste en meter una pelota en un hoyo.*
- **Hueco**: Cavidad, espacio libre entre dos o más sólidos. Lo contrario de "macizo".

  > *Este ladrillo está hueco y por eso pesa poco.*
- **Bache**: Un hoyo en una carretera o camino.

  > *Este camino está lleno de baches.*
- **Agujero**: Apertura más o menos redondeada. (En astronomía, black hole = agujero negro)

  > *Los disparos hicieron varios agujeros en la bandera.*
- **Boquete**: Agujero grande.

  > *El obús hizo un boquete en la pared.*
- **Brecha**: Rotura o apertura irregular.

  > *Las máquinas de asedio abrieron una brecha en las murallas.*
- **Madriguera**: "casa" de los animales como el conejo que consiste en un agujero en el suelo con túneles y dependencias.

  > "*El conejo escapó de los perros al esconderse en su madriguera.*"

Comment: La madrina canta el madrigal desde su madriguera

Comment: Alenanno, gracias por la edición que así queda mejor. Yo estaba editando simultáneamente, espero no haber deshecho tus cambios.

Comment: A correction: "hueco" is (apart from an adjective) also a substantive, similar to "agujero", or perhaps more, "cavidad" (cavity), and in this context this meaning  should be more important.

Comment: Gracias jrdioko por la corrección. Edito la errata. Y leonbloy tiene razón en la otra acepción de "hueco", pero ese significado (acepción 11 del diccionario de la RAE) es en arquitectura "hueco para hacer una puerta"

Comment: I would add: when in doubt, use "agujero" (at least in Spain)

Comment: Just a funny note: "Agujero" can also mean someone that sells needles :D

Answer (score 2):

Well they mean the same thing but there are several different circumstances in which each one is applied more often.

*Agujero* means hole but most of the times means a smaller hole than a *hoyo*.
*Hueco* could mean hole or hollow, but it isn't hard to figure it out with full context.

I've noticed that most of the time when the hole is in a vertical surface (such as a wall) we call it *hueco* or *agujero* not *hoyo*, and when the hole is in an horizontal surface, such as the floor we call it *hoyo* or *agujero* too but not *hueco*.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that, even if colloquially confused, there are conceptual differences. I would group them accordingly:

1. ***hueco***, ***agujero***, ***boquete*** -> referring to *apertures that pass through* a surface, therefore show two sides
2. **bache***, ***hoyo***, ***brecha*** -> are *one sided* cavities that don't pass through. With ***madriguera*** as a special hole in the ground, a
   cave where animals live

Each have their nuances and common usages:

- ***hueco*** and ***agujero*** are closer in meaning and might be called interchangeably

  > "**por los *[*huecos*/*agujeros*]* de la camisa se entreveía su piel avejentada**"
- ***boquete*** has a size (bigger) connotation

  > "**Los *boquetes* sobre su costado parecían productos de cañonazos recientes**"
- ***bache*** is mostly associated to horizontal surfaces, as in holes of a street

  > "**el andar era a los tumbos, malamente esquivando los *baches* del castigado camino** "
- ***hoyo*** an opening in the ground which is blind, that ends there (regardless its depth)

  > **"Los *hoyos* para los postes fueron cavados a igual distancia unos de otros"**
- ***brecha*** is an irregular break that divides something, like the interval that may exist in a table surface, or a separation like a gap ("brecha entre ricos y pobres")

  > "**los esfuerzos fueron puestos a reducir la *brecha* digital, entre los usuarios de tecnología informática y los ignorantes del siglo XXI**"
- ***madriguera*** is for burrow

  > "***La copa da refugio a diversas especies de pájaros, y las
  >   raíces sirven de madriguera a zorros, conejos, ratas de campo y otros animales***"